# TypeScript Generics: infer key of key-value return type from function argument

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have to following function:

```
function x<V = string, K extends string = string>(myKey: K): {[k in K]: V} {
  return null as any;
}
```

I'd like to get rid (or omit) the `K extends string = string` part.

At the moment I have to call it like this:

```
const res = x<number, 'foo'>('foo');   // resulting type: { foo: number }
```

But I don't want to type `foo` twice. I simply want to use it like this:

```
const res = x<number>('foo');
```

Though ideally I'd like to type the function like this:

```
function x<V = string>(myKey: string): {[myKey]: V} {
  return null as any;
}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be posibile in 3.1 to infer just some type arguments with [Named type arguments & partial type argument inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23696).

Until then you can have the function return another function, with the first call specifying the first type parameter and the second inferring the rest

```
function x<V = string>() {
    return function <K extends string = string>(myKey: K): { [k in K]: V } {
        return null as any;
    }
}

x<string>()('foo')
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you also show how it would look like in TypeScript 3.1? I couldn't find a matching example within the linked GitHub issue.

Comment: I think that's because the syntax of the new feature hasn't been finalized yet.  One of the important outstanding issues is how generic definitions will opt in to accepting named type arguments, since that makes the type parameter names part of the API.

Comment: @BenjaminM We are stil waiting on 3.0,  I don't think the 3.1 stuff is ready and might still be subject to a good deal of change, that is why I did not even try to look for a usage example, it's just something to look forward to, and worth mentioning for future readers